# Typescript lambda not able to find node module

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

So I have a simple lambda as an example for the moment as seen here. I am wondering why I get the error and if there is something I am missing in tsconfig.json that means when i run `tsc` it doesn't compile properly. I thought it would include all packages but doesn't seem to be.

```
import { APIGatewayProxyResult, SQSEvent } from "aws-lambda";
import { DynamoDBClient, GetItemCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";

const { DynamoDbSchemaTable } = process.env;

export const lambdaHandler = async (
  event: SQSEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  const payload = JSON.parse(event.Records[0].body);

  const dbClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: "ap-southeast-2" });
  const params = {
    TableName: DynamoDbSchemaTable,
    Key: {
      FormGuid: { N: "7dabb5b8-a404-44a1-97f7-aeaca1dffb3a" },
    },
  };

  try {
    const data = await dbClient.send(new GetItemCommand(params));
    console.log(data);
    // process data.
  } finally {
    // finally.
  }
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: `Queries: ${payload.formGuid}`,
  };
};
```

The issue though is after compiling it generates and index.js and index.js.map that I can see in the AWS console but when I send a message to SQS the lambda errors and shows the following:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "target": "ES2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you deploying your Lambda? Did you upload the node_modules directory as well?

Comment: @NoelLlevares we use Jenkins cicd and that Jenkinsfile organises everything. Doens't look like it is moving the node_modules directory unfortunately. Am I right in suggesting that I definitely need to transpile the typescript as well though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that I hadn't set up the yaml correctly.

This is the main part I changed and it is now working

```
      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: "src/index.lambdaHandler"
```